# Is it possible to serve dynamic images for email?

Tags: image, email, dynamic

What I'm trying to do: Create an email campaign that will have a header image which will be personalized and display the viewers name based on FirstName data.

This may be beyond my current skill level. But I'm wondering if there isn't a service or some kind of library that will do this. I'm thinking what needs to happen is that an image needs to be served somehow that when pinged with a request like http://example.com/images/emailheader?Ralph, would serve an image with Ralph's name in it.

If this were just for the web, that would be easy. I'm not able to wrap my head around how I might do this for email however, and I'm not finding much in the search.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to `http://example.com/images/emailheader?Ralph` you have the ability to do this with names. You'll just have to do the fancy logic on the web site.

Lets use http://placekitten.com as an example because I'd rather look at kittens.

If http://placekitten.com can serve a 640x480 image of a kitten, you can serve an image for a guy named Ralph. Lets say the first name of your email target is 600/480. You would code in: http://placekitten.com/. This will give you an image named http://placekitten.com/600/480.

It would look something like this:

```
<p>Dear <firstname>,</p>
<p>We saw this and thought of you.</p>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/<firstname>" width="600" height="480" alt="<firstname>" style="display:block;"/>
<p>Your friends at StackOverflow.</p>
```

Your email ISP will take , convert it to good old 600/480, and you'd get this:

```
<p>Dear 600/480,</p>
<p>We saw this and thought of you.</p>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/600/480" width="600" height="480" alt="600/480" style="display:block;"/>
<p>Your friends at StackOverflow.</p>
```

Assuming you did your configuration on your web site for everyone named Ralph, gwally or 600/480, those images will show up in their email. There's far more to it than this, but it gets you started.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually what I'm looking for, using the example of placekitten, would be a kitten image with text (in the image), which said, "Hi, Ralph". I found a service which does this, but now I'm wondering how hard this would be to replicate since I have a moderate level of coding skill. The service is https://niftyimages.com/PersonalizedImages